# Windows 10 remove work administrator

Tags: windows, windows-10, administrator

I have left my job and took a PC I had bought with grant money with me (I didn't steal it!).
My account has limited administrator rights, the real administrator is the work organization (I don't understand how this works). So, I cannot change some settings or uninstall antivirus and Windows defender. Windows cannot be activated or updated (for this reason).

The real problem is that I cannot install some programs (it seems to be random, which I can and which I cannot). If I execute the intaller files (exe, as admin, either with mouse or powershell) nothing happens, and no error messages.These are innocent freeware programs, nothing hacked.

Unfortunately my knowledge of OSs and their settings is very limited. Please let me know if more information is needed.

I disable the antivirus and windows defender realtime scan to no avail. I don't see the "allow programs from" option in the settings. There are no restrictions in

Software restriction Policies Defined;  Local Security policies;
Application Control Policies = none

I cannot find anything related to the installers that failed in the event viewer.

User accounts

myself as COMPANYNAME/myname

and Administrator

both in the  administrator group and with full control privileges.

However,

**I am in the "COMPANY" domain** and
the **administrator is in the "computer name" domain**

I guess this domain business is the key. Maybe I can change my domain?

Can somebody suggest how to fix these problems (without reinstalling Windows)?

OS
Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LSTB (anything else?)

Many thanks

Comment: As I see it: first of all the OS license is for W10 Enterprise and belongs to the company, so you should reinstall Windows with a Home/Pro license or use the trial version.

Comment: Well, I am not sure if once installed it doesn't become right-to-use. I think I will have to reinstall Windows but I dread doing it. Hopefully someone can suggest a work around solution.

Comment: You need to reach out to the *real administrator* as you put it and see what they are willing to do for you.

Comment: This is a good idea. I wonder if they will even reply.